# Is there a way to trigger rateItem API as a Sonos control device?

Tags: sonos

We currently use the Sonos Control REST API to communicate with the players. We would like to  trigger the SMAPI rateItem for the currently playing item (like the Sonos APP does).

1. Is it possible by using only the Control API?
2. or is there a chance to get the SMAPI URL of the service by the serviceId used by the Control API, so that we can send the rateItem request directly to that service?
3. Is there also a JSON REST API available for the SMAPI or is it still only SOAP?

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. No
2. is the way to go, but you need to have figured out the auth secrets etc in order to get the url of the service, as well as the user credentials.
3. The devices only do SOAP APIs. JSON APIs are only used for the cloud API (and for the local, private version of that).

I have never taken my SMAPI support as far as the rating stuff. Older versions of my apps did support the Pandora Like button, but that was when Sonos used the old Pandora API, before they switched it over to SMAPI.